# wxpython problems with binding windows toast notification handler

Tags: python, notifications, wxpython

i am trying to make a windows 10 toast notification that will run code if its clicked but my code only shows the notification and gives me an error when i click it

```
import os
import wx
import wx.adv


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        sTitle = 'test'
        sMsg = 'test'
        nmsg = wx.adv.NotificationMessage(title=sTitle, message=sMsg)
        nmsg.SetFlags(wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        nmsg.Show(timeout=wx.adv.NotificationMessage.Timeout_Auto)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_CLICK, self.notifclicked)
        return True
    def _notifclicked(self, evt):
        print("notification has been clicked")
app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

error code : AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'EVT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_CLICK'

Comment: Where did you get the name of that `event`? I don't believe it exists. You may be confusing `wx.adv.NotificationMessage` with `notify2` a separate package that does allow you to add actions.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony i found it in the docs on the wxpython website [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.NotificationMessage.html) in the Events Emitted by this Class section. I might have misunderstood the docs im still new to python so theres a big chance i mixed it up with something theres also an AddAction command that i would want to use too but i cant find any information about it it only has writen in the docs that it needs an actionID and a label but i dont even know what is an actionID

Answer (score 0):

Without wishing to say definitely that `NotificationMessage` is unfinished business, I'm going to suggest it.

I suspect that it is based on `notify` and `notify2` which purport to support `action` callbacks but don't.
They should be relying on Dbus sending stuff back but it doesn't look like it does or you have to jump through hoops to make it happen. (Dbus MainLoop setup for example)

I have decided to adapt your code slightly, just to show how to add `action` buttons, although they are nothing more than eye candy and to show how I think the event callbacks should work, if it ever comes to reality.

Of course, if it currently does work and I haven't worked out how to do it, I'll happily eat these words. I code exclusively on Linux, so there's that as a caveat.

```
import wx
import wx.adv

Act_Id_1 = wx.NewIdRef()
Act_Id_2 = wx.NewIdRef()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", size=(360,100)):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, size)
        self.m_no = 0
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Mbutton = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Fire off a message", pos=(10,10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnFire, self.Mbutton)
        #self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_CLICK, self._notifclicked)
        #self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_DISMISSED, self._notifdismissed)
        #self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_ACTION, self._notifaction, id=Act_Id_1)
        self.Show()

    def OnFire(self, event):
        self.m_no +=1
        sTitle = 'Test heading'
        sMsg = 'Test message No '
        nmsg = wx.adv.NotificationMessage(title=sTitle, message=sMsg+str(self.m_no))
        nmsg.SetFlags(wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        nmsg.AddAction(Act_Id_1, "Cancel")
        nmsg.AddAction(Act_Id_2, "Hold")
        nmsg.Show(timeout=10)

    def _notifclicked(self, event):
        print("notification has been clicked")
    def _notifdismissed(self, event):
        print("notification dismissed")
    def _notifaction(self, event):
        print("Action")
app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: welp i found out that there is [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) on microsofts website i got that working but i dont know anything about c# or c++ so i have to do some more reasearch to make it work